# I have a netbook I can't format (for legal reasons) and cannot upgrade from the terminal to Ubuntu 14.04 from 10.04

Tags: upgrade, 10.04

I have a netbook that we're given during high school for educational purposes, which has a Linux, and now that I'm in college I want to start using it. It has Ubuntu 10.~ and when I use the sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade it gives the message "0 things found, 0 to be updated".

I would just format the PC if I could and install 14.04 from a USB like the guides say, but it is still protected with a program that prevents you from altering the PC like that.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Can Ubuntu be 'forcefully' upgraded?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is the option to just do a clean install from a current version - provided you are entitled to (the use of 'legally' in your question suggests not, but if it's an ex-school one, now yours then you can do what you like..).

Backup any important files to external drive first, boot from a USB (or CD) & you have total control over your old drive, no matter what's been installed on it. If the computer won't boot from USB then you need to hunt through BIOS to find why - there's alway 'reset to defaults' if you can't.

Upgrading from archaic versions, my experience has been that it balks if too old (& I think 10.04 may be).

If these answers don't help you, a bit more detail (eg which netbook, what happens when you try) may open things up a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the only way this would be possible would be to do sequential upgrades. First upgrade from Lucid Lynx (10.04) to Precise Pangolin (12.04); then upgrade from 12.04 to Trusty Tahr (14.04). Read the [Upgrade Notes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes#From_10.04_LTS_to_12.04_LTS) for how to conduct these steps. You should also read [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu) carefully.

However, it may behoove you to find someone with some expertise who is able to remove the program that prevents you from reformatting. Is the laptop your property or does it still belong to the school?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing package updates not a system upgrade. Try this instead:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

That should take you from 10.04 to 12.04, then once that's done and you've tested it and are happy, you can do it again to take it from 12.04 to 14.04.